# OnbeforeUnload и сообщение о несохраненных данных

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

У меня ситуация такова:

1.на основном окне в форме вводятся данные,

2.они не сохраняются,

3.затем эта форма открывается в отдельном окне,

4.которое сразу же закрывают.

При закритии стоит ивент onbeforeunload который должен привести в действие дефолтное модальное окно, а затем если пользователь нажал Cancel - появляется кастомное окно. 
Но в описаной выше ситуации отдельное окно закривается, только видно как мeлькает кастомное окошко. Модальное даже не показывается. Но при дебаге срабатывает как должно быть.

И если между 3 і 4 пунктами вставить клик в любой области отдельного окна - все тоже работает как должно.
Вот код связан с onbeforeunload (пробовала вставить `window.focus();` внутри - не помогло):

```
var answerEvent =  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
                if (!this.reopenInTearOff && window.itemsVault.isDirtyEx(window.item)) {
                    confirmExitEditMode().then(function (shouldCloseWindow) {
                        if (shouldCloseWindow) {
                            window.close();
                        }
                    });
                    (e || window.event).returnValue =  window.itemsVault.getResource('', 'item_methods_ex.changes_not_saved');
                    return window.itemsVault.getResource('', 'item_methods_ex.unsaved_changes');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Для борьбы с нежелательными всплывающими окнами некоторые браузеры не
>   отражают подсказки, созданные перед обработкой событий, если только
>   эта страница не взаимодействует; некоторые из них вообще не
>   отображаются.

Источник: [WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)